# What's the rate of convergence of this series?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

> Let
>
> $$S_{n} = \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \cdots +
>  (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{n!} = \sum_{k=2}^{n} (-1)^{k}\frac{1}{k!}.$$
>
> a) What does $S_{n}$ converge to? Denote the limit point by $L$.
>
> b) How quickly does it converge to $L$? For example, say something
>   like, $|S_{n} - L| \sim \frac{1}{n}$.

For $(a)$, I'm pretty sure the answer is $e^{-1}$. I've got the answer to $(a)$ down, but I don't really know how to do part $(b)$.

By just plugging in values for $S_{n}$, it seems to converge pretty quickly, but I'm not able to provide a good estimation. Also, even if I am able to provide an estimation, I have no idea how to check whether or not it's correct. I was wondering if someone can please help me and show me how to check the rate of convergence (e.g. check if the guess is correct)

Thanks so much

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation), $|S_n - L|  \le \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the convergence from the Taylor Series of $e^x,$ so the limit is correct.

I can't provide you with the least upper bound for the error, but I can tell you how to find a bound.

Implicitly $n\geq2$. We compute
$$\left|S_n-L\right|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty(-1)\frac{1}{k!}\right|=\frac{1}{n!}\left|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-\ldots\right|$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\ldots\right)$$
$$\leq\frac{2}{n!(n+1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)(n+3)}+\ldots\right)$$
$$|S_n-L|\leq\frac{2(e-1)}{n!(n+1)}=\frac{2(e-1)}{(n+1)!}.$$